# Document viewer browser plugin

Tags: plugins, cross-browser, npapi, browser-plugin, documentviewer

I am developing a cross browser plugin for document viewing (.pdf, .doc, .xls, .mht, .tiff, .dwg). It needs to be a plugin and not the extension. Whatever i try to search takes me to the links for extensions and not for plugins. I found NPAPI as cross platform plugin architecture but soon found out that major browsers have planned to depreciate and stop the development support, Chrome is one of them.  I have been searching from last 3 days and finding myself in no man's land.

I intend to develop the tool as a business requirement and not use some already developed software tools like quickview. Please provide some good links to the cross browser plugin development. A little help will mean a lot. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The only truly cross-browser technology, supported by all the major browsers, are standardized or standards-track web technologies. If you want something that works in all browsers, you'll need to develop using the technologies that browsers are designed and intended to support.

The reason you aren't finding any resources for doing what you describe is that there's no way to do it.